# asp.net label over asp.net image

Tags: asp.net

I want to palce a asp.net label over asp.net image

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/option.PNG" /> 
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Labelsssssss"></asp:Label>
```

here it will come one after another only. I have to use both asp controls no html controls are allowed.How?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put a label over an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412400/how-to-put-a-label-over-an-image)

Comment: no.here both image and label are asp controls . Html controls are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

if possible, remove the image, put the label in a div, set the background-image of the div to your image.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnl">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl" Text="this is text" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
```

CS page:

```
 pnl.Attributes.Add("style", "background:url(/option.PNG)");
```